# functions to modify an octomap

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I have an octomap in the form of .bt file, and I am able to read and translate it as an OcTree. I hope to rotate or move this octomap with respect to global frame and write it out as .bt file. Are there any functions or examples I can look into?  I was reading the documentation of Pose6D and Vector3 but had no idea how to connect these two classes with OcTree.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47516/functions-to-modify-an-octomap/) by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Pose6D defines a transformation. What you'd basically have to do:

- Create a new empty OcTree
- Iterate over your OcTree's cells
- For each cell:

  - Transform its coordinates using your transform
  - Insert this cell at the transformed coordinates into the empty OcTree

However, this is very inefficient and at the same time the only way of doing that in principle. You'll need to identify your use case for that to decide if you really need to do this, otherwise, follow @jj56's advice.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0